# How pass the right side "where" to an IQueryable instantiation in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to abstract my `IQueryable` call so that I can pass the where into a function:

Something like:

```
public IQueryable<T> executeQuery<T>(T baseType, Expression<Func<T,object>> whereFunc) where T : class 
{
    //Get context
    DataContext dbContext = new DataContext(connection);

    //Get the table representation
    Table<T> baseTable = dbContext.GetTable<T>();

    //Get our query object
    IQueryable<T> baseQuery = from item in baseTable where whereFunc select item;
}
```

The above doesn't work, but is there some way to do this? (i.e. generically create the IQueryable but allow passing in the where clause?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `whereFunc` signature is wrong. `Where` is a filter so should return `bool`, not `object`. Also, you cannot use simplified linq syntax in this case. This should work:

```
public IQueryable<T> executeQuery<T>(T baseType, Expression<Func<T,bool>> whereFunc) where T : class 
{
    //Get context
    DataContext dbContext = new DataContext(connection);

    //Get the table representation
    Table<T> baseTable = dbContext.GetTable<T>();

    //Get our query object
    IQueryable<T> baseQuery = baseTable.Where(whereFunc);
}
```